# Export Tableau Data to CSV

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple text table in Tableau. The "View Data" option is not listed when I right-click the table, therefore I'm not being able to export the table to csv.

This doesn't occur when the worksheet is a chart/graph, only if it's a table. Screenshot attached

[image: TABLEAU TABLE]

Answer (score 0):

Press alt 
Then w
Then c 
Then again c

This is a short cut to copy cross tab.

Paste this in a excel file by using the below shortcut: 
Open new excel file press ctrl + v
There you go!